# Decrypt files encrypted with gpg using xargs

Tags: xargs, gpg

I have a lot of files encrypted with *gpg*. All files have the same password. Is it possible to use xargs to decrypt files?

`ls | xargs -n 1 gpg` asks for the password for every file.

Comment: You could save your password to a variable which gpg can be called with.  It's also a good idea to avoid depending on the output of ls for operations such as this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run [gpg-agent](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html) or a similar program. Set up gpg to look for a running agent, as explained in the documentation. Enter the passphrase in the agent once and for all (for this session).

Note that `ls | xargs -n 1 gpg` only works if your file names do not contain any special characters. Generally speaking, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and `xargs` is pointless when you want to run the program once per file. Do this instead:

```
for x in *.gpg; do gpg "$x"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this :

```
for i in *; do 
  /usr/bin/gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 3  --decrypt $i 3<pass > $i.decoded ; 
done
```

When "pass" is a complete path to a file that contains your passphrase.

Files will be decoded to [same name].decoded.

Comment: Don't use * here.   Use ./* so that you can be sure that the expansion of `$i` does not begin with `-` (making it look like another option).

Comment: Can also use `--passphrase` or `--passphrase-file` instead.

Comment: @JamesYoungman nice tip, +1